# How to add a horizontal scrollbar to ListBox in Domino Designer

Tags: listbox, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a form in my hands with listbox on it. There was a demand to display horizontal scrollbar for this listbox since users are unable to fully read text in the right column.

Is there any way to do so?

[how does it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSkij.jpg)

[desing of subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLUT8.jpg)

Comment: I've just tried it and horizontal scroll bar appeared automatically.
1) what version of Lotus Notes do you use? 
2) can you show photo of how you build dialog in designer?
3) can you show example of code how you trigger dialog?

Comment: 1). 8.0.2  

2). by the link "desing of subform" in main message  

3).

ws.DialogBox("InventoryAddToFile",True,True,False,False,False,False,"some text")

Answer (score 3):

Try to get rid off Layout and use table instead.
It seems to be limitation of layouts. It works if you do not use Layouts.

[image]

Here is how my subform looks like:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Layouts have essentially been deprecated for more than a decade because they had so many limitations like this.

Comment: oh yes I remember! the layout had the power to make interface so "wahou!" but all the time there were limitations that after hours of research conducted to abandon them... too bad because it could have given us in some conplexe case a real power to built pretty cool interfaces